# Can I set the parameters in a matlab function in simulink to be tunable?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I want to tune some parameters of a matlab function block in simulink with Dashboard Blocks like knobs. But when i click on the matlab function with the parameter I want to tune, it says that this block has no tunable parameters. How can I change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no way to get a tunable parameter in such a block. To get the functionality, I recommend make an input port out of the parameter you want to tune. Then connect it to a constant block and tune the constant instead.